# I want to add a chart control inside a UL tag in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to dynamically add chart controls inside my ul tags through code. How can I do this?
 This is my statement for the anythingslider javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var slider2 = ['Machines', 'Trend','test','test2','test3'];
     function formatText(index, panel) {
         return slider2[index - 1];
     }

     $(function () {
         $('#slider2').anythingSlider({
             width: 800,       // if resizeContent is false, this is the default width if panel size is not defined
             height: 400,       // if resizeContent is false, this is the default height if panel size is not defined
             buildArrows: true,
             resizeContents: false,     // If true, solitary images/objects in the panel will expand to fit the viewport
             autoPlay: true,     // This turns off the entire slideshow FUNCTIONALY, not just if it starts running or not
             navigationFormatter: formatText, // Format navigation labels with text
             forwardText: "&raquo;",
             backText: "&laquo;"
         })
     });
</script>
```

Edit:
This is the source code to the page with the new added code:

```
<ul id="MainContent_slider2">
<img id="MainContent_PlantMachineChart" src="/ChartImg.axd?i=chart_93717cef16e84387b35d83bdd04da217_0.png&amp;g=898a170672b0476ca6f6d49173c231b1" alt="" usemap="#MainContent_PlantMachineChartImageMap"    style="height:400px;width:868px;border-width:0px;" />

<map name="MainContent_PlantMachineChartImageMap"  id="MainContent_PlantMachineChartImageMap">
 </map>

 <li><img id="MainContent_ctl01" src="/ChartImg.axd?    i=chart_93717cef16e84387b35d83bdd04da217_1.png&amp;g=23020f9898ab40898782de3234fae6e4"    alt="" style="height:400px;width:868px;border-width:0px;" /></li'><li'><img    id="MainContent_ctl03" src="/ChartImg.axd?   i=chart_93717cef16e84387b35d83bdd04da217_2.png&amp;g=aa749f6279484859a7892f1f117fbd1c"    alt="" style="height:400px;width:868px;border-width:0px;" /></li></ul>
```

It has all the data points listed for the first chart(which I left out here) which isn't added dynmically.

Comment: My answer will work for you; however, is there a reason you are wanting the charts in a `ul`?

Comment: I guess it doesn't Have to be a UL. I guess just an html container in general. And your answer doesn't work for my application. What I really need is to insert     

<asp:Chart ID="PlantMachineChart" runat="server"
           Height="400px" Width="868px">
                <series>
                    <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Line" ChartArea="MainChartArea">
            </asp:Chart>

into the tag

Comment: Create the asp Chart on the server and insert the control in. It isnt going to work if you try to just put that content into the ul.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example I have found.

Comment: using the controls.add isn't exactly working. I'm using this javascript: [link](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/) to show multiple charts without making the page larger. When I use the controls.add it just puts all the charts on one slide rather than separating the slides. Any ideas?

Comment: You are going to have to dynamically create the lis too. I cant really help you without seeing the code you are working with.

Comment: edited my original post with code

Comment: Have you tried creating the chart on the server as mentioned in my answer? You could probably do this in a repeater if you did it correctly.

Comment: Also to note you dont even have the lis in your given code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont really know why you would want to do this, but you can make the ul `runat="server"` and add the controls to it like so:

**HTML**:

```
<ul runat="server" ID="ul_Charts"></ul>
```

**ServerSide**:

```
ul_Charts.Controls.Add(yourControl);
```

**Edit**: You need to programmatically create the chart and insert the chart control into your element like this:

```
// Create a pie chart
Chart chart = new Chart();

// Choose chart type and add series info
Series series = new Series("Default");
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
chart.Series.Add(series);

// Create chart legend
Legend legend = new Legend();
chart.Legends.Add(legend);

// Define the chart area
ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
ChartArea3DStyle areaStyle = new ChartArea3DStyle(chartArea);
areaStyle.Rotation = 0;
chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

Axis yAxis = new Axis(chartArea, AxisName.Y);
Axis xAxis = new Axis(chartArea, AxisName.X);

// Bind the data to the chart
chart.Series["Default"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);

// Add chart
HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
li.Controls.Add(chart);
ul_Charts.Controls.Add(li);
```

This example was found on the [asp.net forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1354675.aspx/1) and was tweaked a little to fit your scenario. There are other options but this should at list give an idea of what you need to do.

Comment: ok, so how can I use the anythingslider with the panel rather than the ul? What do I do with the image after it's saved to add it to the panel?

Comment: You cannot do it with a panel. You did not tell me about the anything slider until a few minutes ago. Note the answer was last edited 21 minutes ago.

Comment: This was just example code you will have to change to your scenario. You could most likely just add the chart control to your ul.

Comment: haha ok sorry about that, then I guess i'll keep the ul, but to the main question: how do I add the saved chart to the UL now? controls.add is still not giving me the results I'm trying to get.

Comment: I have updated the code to be more specific, but you still have not shown how you are even adding the charts.

Comment: I'm adding the charts just as you specified in your example. It's still not seperating. All the charts show up, just not in seperate slider windows.

Comment: Did you add the part about the lis? I just updated the code to show you how to add the lis too. If you dont have the lis, then of course it is all going to be on one slide.

Comment: yea I did, edited my post with the source code that's generated from the page.

Comment: Your first chart does not have the li.

Comment: Yea I caught that right after I posted it, added it, still doing the same thing.

Comment: What is it doing now? If you have an li for each chart then it should be working properly if you setup the slider correctly. You need to take your time and focus on your code. It seems like you are in way too much of a rush and are making dumb mistakes. Take your time and think through what you are needing to do and what the end result of your code should look like so that the slider works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a placeholder in the aspx and then load the control into it at run time.

Comment: The only problem with this is I have also have a dynamic number of charts to add during each page load. I tried using a repeater but the charts don't show up.